# Am I RICEing my injury?

Tags: suffixes, acronyms, progressive-aspect, ing

**R**est, **I**cing, **C**ompression and **E**levation after an injury, and repeat as needed for the first couple hours.

Using RICE, how would I type the answer to the question, "How's your twisted ankle?"?

"Not so good, I'm just RICEing it" or "Not so good, I'm just RICing it"?

Comment: What research have you yourself done?

Comment: Google search. It's a novel question about using an acronym ending with an E and the suffix -ing.

Comment: You should post the [lack of] results you find. As surlawda says, 'But this usage is so informal ... that you are not likely to find any author[i]tative answer. In essence, you are making something up to serve your own purposes.' Such questions do not fit well with ELU's format.

Comment: I'd go with "RICEing".  If you eliminate the "E" you lose part of the acronym, and you cause it to be pronounced differently.

Comment: Compare 'tasing' vs. 'tasering'. Note also that the idea that RICE is good has been recanted by the originator (in 2014, after inventing the acronym in 1978). Ice especially, but also complete rest, may not be such a hot idea. Inflammation may help injuries heal more quickly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no rule about this. Many times a short acronym takes an apostrophe:

> The bouncer is ID'ing people.

but you're as likely to see

> The bouncer is IDing people.

Your example is a bit different, and personally I'd go with

> I'm just RICEing it.

In this case, the "E" has an actual meaning and should, IMO, be kept. "RICing" could be construed as "I'm using RIC on it."

But this usage is so informal, so colloquial, that you are not likely to find any authoratative answer. In essence, you are making something up to serve your own purposes. In formal writing, you likely would not use it. A quick look at three or four sports therapy websites reveals no use of this term in verb form

Comment: To clarify a bit more, I probably would use "ID'ing" rather than "IDing" because it is pronounced "eye-dee-ing," not "eye-ding." In the example asked about, I believe "RICEing" and "RICing" would have the same pronunciation, so keep the E and omit the apostrophe. But, again, that's just the way I see it. This is a matter of editorial style. Different people have different opinions.

Comment: +1. But note that true acronyms frequently lose their all-caps spelling -- for example, light amplification by stimulated emission of radiation is commonly known as *laser*, not *LASER* -- and if that happens with *RICE*, then the -ing form will almost certainly be *ricing*, not *riceing*. (Cf. *lasing*.)

Comment: @ruakh Very true. But I can't think of very many acronyms that have a verb form, and one like RICE (or rice) may be especially resistant to that. Let's hope so, anyway.

Comment: @ruakh, I suggest this is less common for acronyms that would be homonyms or common words (such as *RICE*, *Navy SEALS*).  In fact there are plenty of initlialisms and similar abbreviations  that could be pronounced as a common word but are spelt out (*ID*, to use an example already here).

Comment: @ChrisH: In fact, [*Navy Seal* is well-attested](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Navy+Seal%2CNavy+Seals%2CNavy+SEAL%2CNavy+SEALs%2CNavy+SEALS&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CNavy%20Seal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNavy%20Seals%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNavy%20SEAL%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNavy%20SEALs%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CNavy%20SEALS%3B%2Cc0). (Incidentally, the official capitalization is *SEALs* rather than *SEALS*.) And I don't understand your second point; it doesn't seem related at all.

Comment: @ruakh perhap it was over-compressed into a comment. A familiar  pre-existing word may encourage adoption (of a spelling or pronuciation), but there's an opposing pressure to avoid ambiguity. (The "S" was careless, btw)

Answer (score 3):

Since you can't  actually  do all four at once,  i'd say I'm elevating it  or compressing it, etc.  I'm treating it  using the rice technique

Comment: I'd like to use RICE. The question is about typing the final E or not. Thanks.

Comment: I think you can physically do all four at once, though. Lay down, elevate your foot (or whatever it is) wrapped in compression tape, but a bag of ice on it. Since you can't move, you're also resting. Boom.

Answer (score 2):

In conversation, you'd probably either be more specific and long-hand, or a lot more general.

If the person you're talking to needs to know the details:

> I've been keeping my feet up (rest and elevation), using some compression and putting some ice on it.

If someone's asked how you're doing, you'd probably not even give them the acronym.

> Oh, you know, I've been taking it easy, until it feels better.

Comment: Texting to the coach

Comment: @Drakes There's quite a lot of language that develops organically in specific groups of people (e.g. industries, sports teams, fans of a particular band). So if your coach says RICEing, then it's definitely acceptable to say it back to them, because you know it'll be understood.

Comment: I have a small phone which is hard to text on. I tried to convey my actions succinctly. No idea what he says, actually. Thanks.